# Blazor WASM - Spending a long time initially in Authorizing component

Tags: blazor-webassembly

My Blazor WASM (hosted) app is spending quite a long time (~10s) in the authentication process when I open the webpage for the first time and eventually logs

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

Afterwards, it continues to show all content which is not wrapped in an `Authorized` tag.

In `App.razor` I use the `Authorizing` component and it shows its content ("Determining session state...") for a long time until it continues (see `App.razor` below).

The authentication in my app happens through an endpoint `/authentication/login` which forwards the user to Auth0 as identity provider using the

```
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
```

component and the configuration in `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Auth0", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalProviderParameters.Add(
         "audience",  builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"]);
});
```

---

App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <Authorizing>
                    <p>Determining session state, please wait...</p>
                </Authorizing>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h1>Sorry</h1>
                    <p>You are not authorized to view this page</p>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Source of issue

The issue is caused by a timeout in the underlying implementation of the authentication services. I traced down the source, but there's no easy solution to this issue.

If you enable Debug tracing for your WASM client, you should see this log message in the console:

> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService[0]
> Initial silent sign in failed 'Frame window timed out'

For me - using Keycloak (instead of Auth0), and Discord as IdP behind Keycloak -  the Discord login cannot be framed in the hidden iframe:

> Refused to frame 'https://discord.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' my.domain.com".

Of course this policy can be modified to include `discord.com`, but Discord denies being embedded that way with `X-Frame-Options` header.

### What's happening

1. The app gets loaded
2. `AuthorizeViewCore` is being rendered, entering [`OnParametersSetAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0e94423f0ef587b8fe262667c8168e14e4f5ac7/src/Components/Authorization/src/AuthorizeViewCore.cs#LL71C5-L93C1):

   ```cs
   // Clear the previous result of authorization
   // This will cause the Authorizing state to be displayed until the authorization has been completed
   isAuthorized = null;

   currentAuthenticationState = await AuthenticationState;
   isAuthorized = await IsAuthorizedAsync(currentAuthenticationState.User);
   ```
3. The `AuthenticationState` is initialized by [`RemoteAuthenticationService.GetAuthenticationStateAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0e94423f0ef587b8fe262667c8168e14e4f5ac7/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/Services/RemoteAuthenticationService.cs#LL104C1-L104C141):

   ```cs
   new AuthenticationState(await GetUser(useCache: true));
   ```
4. This will invoke `GetAuthenticatedUser`:

   ```cs
   /// <summary>
   /// Gets the current authenticated used using JavaScript interop.
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns>A <see cref="Task{ClaimsPrincipal}"/>that will return the current authenticated user when completes.</returns>
   protected internal virtual async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> GetAuthenticatedUser()
   {
       await EnsureAuthService();
       var account = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<TAccount>("AuthenticationService.getUser");
       var user = await AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreateUserAsync(account, Options.UserOptions);

       return user;
   }
   ```
5. [`AuthenticationService.getUser`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0e94423f0ef587b8fe262667c8168e14e4f5ac7/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/Interop/AuthenticationService.ts#LL141C5-L150C6) will invoke `trySilentSignIn`:

   ```js
       async trySilentSignIn() {
       if (!this._intialSilentSignIn) {
           this._intialSilentSignIn = (async () => {
               try {
                   this.debug('Beginning initial silent sign in.');
                   await this._userManager.signinSilent();
                   this.debug('Initial silent sign in succeeded.');
               } catch (e) {
                   if (e instanceof Error) {
                       this.debug(`Initial silent sign in failed '${e.message}'`);
                   }
                   // It is ok to swallow the exception here.
                   // The user might not be logged in and in that case it
                   // is expected for signinSilent to fail and throw
               }
           })();
       }

       return this._intialSilentSignIn;
   }
   ```
6. The `await this._userManager.signinSilent();` will invoke the **oidc-client-js** [UserManager](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/UserManager.js) `signinSilent` and then `_signinSilentIframe`:

   ```js
   _signinSilentIframe(args = {}) {
       let url = args.redirect_uri || this.settings.silent_redirect_uri || this.settings.redirect_uri;
       if (!url) {
           Log.error("UserManager.signinSilent: No silent_redirect_uri configured");
           return Promise.reject(new Error("No silent_redirect_uri configured"));
       }

       args.redirect_uri = url;
       args.prompt = args.prompt || "none";

       return this._signin(args, this._iframeNavigator, {
           startUrl: url,
           silentRequestTimeout: args.silentRequestTimeout || this.settings.silentRequestTimeout
       }).then(user => {
           if (user) {
               if (user.profile && user.profile.sub) {
                   Log.info("UserManager.signinSilent: successful, signed in sub: ", user.profile.sub);
               }
               else {
                   Log.info("UserManager.signinSilent: no sub");
               }
           }

           return user;
       });
   }
   ```
7. Finally, this will end up at [`IFrameWindow.js`](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/IFrameWindow.js), which has **a timeout of 10000 ms** configured:

   ```js
   const DefaultTimeout = 10000;
   ```
8. The initially logged **timeout error** is thrown:

   ```js
   _timeout() {
       Log.debug("IFrameWindow.timeout");
       this._error("Frame window timed out");
   }
   ```